# NVM issue after recovery/reinstall ubuntu

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, nvm

Over the weekend I had to performed a fresh install on Ubuntu on my laptop. 
I was restoring my files from my backup, but I used the wrong username. 
I've tried to change the username and the $PATH but I'm still getting the same error

```
t0m@asuntu:~$ wget -qO- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.33.8/install.sh | bash
=> Downloading nvm from git to '/home/ubut0m/.nvm'
=> mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/home/ubut0m’: Permission denied
ls: cannot access '/home/ubut0m/.nvm': No such file or directory
fatal: could not create leading directories of '/home/ubut0m/.nvm': Permission denied
Failed to clone nvm repo. Please report this!
t0m@asuntu:~$ vim .bashrc 
t0m@asuntu:~$
```

I've tried removing and reinstalling everthing (NPM, Node, NVM), but don't know why I can't get the script to work. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

- **Check that you're `$HOME` environment variable matches that of the user you are currently running as, which you can check with `whoami`.** Sometimes, some tools that elevate privileges (such as `sudo`) preserve the old user's home directory environment variable while running as the new user.
- If that's not the problem, **check that your home directory exists and has the correct permissions**. Usually, if that's the problem, all sorts of other issues pop up (but I can understand a tendency to ignore such things on a newly restored machine).
- If it's neither of those things, you can try making sure that you are in your home directory when running the `wget | bash` command although that really shouldn't be necessary (and if that turns out to be the issue, I would definitely file a bug with `nvm` about it).

Comment: hey @Trott I've run `echo $HOME` to see what came up and `whoami` and they both match (t0m). 

I might not be following your other two suggestions

Comment: I was able to get it working by hardcoding my $HOME into the configuration file in npm.